# How to fill a hill with a custom texture using OpenGl?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to learn OpenGl be reading various tutorials, so I was looking at http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

In that tutorial, he basically takes a texture with stripes:

[image: Rectangular texture with stripes]

And wraps it around a hill to look like:

[image: Hills with stripes]

Her creates the vertices and texture coordinates, by taking the coordinates of the top of the hill and creating a triangle strip

```
    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0 + minY);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt0.x/512, 1.0f);
    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, 0 + minY);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt1.x/512, 1.0f);

    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt0.x/512, 0);
    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, pt1.y);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt1.x/512, 0);
```

My question is, what if I had the same texture with stripes, but wanted to render it on to the hills without distortion ? You will notice from the hill image, that the texture is somewhat wrapped around the hills (so all the stripes are curved), but how would I apply the texture so it is straight lines exactly like the original image ?

I am using OpenGl-es 2.0.

EDIT.

I tried setting the texture-coordinates the same as the vertex coordinates, but it didn't work out exactly as I hoped:

[image: My texture]

[image]

The first image shows the texture. And the second image is the effect when applied to the hills. The stripes are no longer "wavy", but they seem much larger than the original texture, and seem to be oriented the wrong way. How do I correct this ? My modified code is

```
    _hillTexCoords[tcc++]=CGPointMake(p0.x/512, 0+_minY);
    _hillTexCoords[tcc++]=CGPointMake(p0.x/512, p0.y/512);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this in 3D you must understand what you are asking for is getting a 2D screen projection of model(the hill) and applying the texture on that projection.

The most robust way of doing this is creating a stencil buffer and drawing the hill onto it. Then draw a fullscreen textured quad using that stencil buffer so that the quad is drawn only where stencil is TRUE (the hill is visible).

Pretty much the same can be done with alpha channel. Use colour mask to draw the hill only to alpha channel and then use blending to draw a full screen textured quad where alpha is 1.

If you have the access to the shaders you could use the fragment shader to get the relative screen coordinates of every fragment so that top left corner is (0,0) and bottom right is (1,1) then use these coordinates to get the image texel instead of using texture coordinates from the model.

Comment: I'm not trying to do this in 3d. I'm just trying to make the texture s appear straight (like in the first picture), but within the hill area.

Comment: I think I see your confusion - this hill itself is not 3d. It just looks like that because the texture (first image) gets distorted, the way it is used.

Comment: Ah, then all you need to do is have the same texture coordinates as the vertex coordinates but they have to be in rage (0,1) so simply divided by width and height...

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand - but since the hills are much wider than the texture, eventually the vertex coordinate will be larger than the texture width anyway. I tried what you said and got some unexpected results. See above.

Comment: This seems almost good. Looks like you need to invert either x or y coordinate (1-x) and that 512 is not the full size but a smaller value. Try finding out what is the largest X value on vertex coordinate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by invert. The largest X value could be some huge number. I keep drawing hills so I don't think it makes sense to think of any max value for x right now.

Comment: Then just divide it with some smaller value. This values depends on how often the stripes appear..

Comment: I finally understood what you meant. I use modf to keep that range between 0 and 1, and that works.